# Excel: SUM multiple lines by YEAR

Tags: excel

I need a formula to sum the amount of dividends payed per year.

Column A shows the date and column B shows the amount payed.

Example of my data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/layJy.png

I've tried IF with SUM, SUMIF, VLOOKUP, etc., but no success.

Thanks.

Comment: Show the formulas you tried.  You can also do this easily with a Pivot Table.

Comment: It would be nice if you could show what you have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your need, it seems that **Pivot Table** is your Solution instead of using if, Sum or anything else.

You can watch this example from **Efficiency 365**: [Pivot Table Date Grouping Tutorial: How to group on year, month, quarter, day, or hour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=24jr3ZUbQS4)

Here is your end result:

[image: Pivot Table Example]

Comment: Thanks Tsiriniaina! The pivot table was so simple and easy that I gave up trying to create formulas.

Comment: I'm happy I could help. Blessings!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the dividend per year is in column C and the first cell is C2. In such case, try this macro:

```
Sub DividendPerYearFormula()

    Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(YEAR(R[-1]C[-2])=YEAR(RC[-2]),"""",SUMIFS(C[-1],C[-2],""<""&DATE(YEAR(RC[-2]),12,31),C[-2],"">""&DATE(YEAR(RC[-2]),1,1)))"

End Sub
```

The formula itself is:

```
=IF(YEAR(A1)=YEAR(A2),"",SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,""<""&DATE(YEAR(A2),12,31),A:A,"">""&DATE(YEAR(A2),1,1)))
```

It will show you the value once per year. It is possible to have the values repeated in each row too. Of course a pivot table is also a good option.

Comment: Thanks for you help. The pivot table was so easy that I gave up the formulas.